# Android- status bar notification with progress bar

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar, download, statusbar

I currently have a status bar notification that goes off when an mp3 is downloaded from a url. It launches fine (and the file does download fine), however, the progress bar doesn't progress. It simply stays still. I'm not sure where to put the code so it notify's the progress of the download. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Here is part of my code:

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                URL url2 = new URL(sdrUrl);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                int lengthOfFile = c.getContentLength();

                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/";
                Log.v("", "PATH: " + PATH);
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();

                String [] path = url2.getPath().split("/");
                String mp3 = path [path.length-1];
                String sdrMp3 = mp3.replace("%20", "");

                File outputFile = new File(file, sdrMp3);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    publishProgress((int)(len1*100/lengthOfFile));
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();

                }catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {


            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }



    }

    public void DownloadNotification(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BlogActivity.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.sdricontest, "Downloading...", System
               .currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.download_icon, R.drawable.sdricontest);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_text, "simulation in progress");
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, 100, progress, false);

        getApplicationContext();
        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following -

```
    public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public DownloadFile() {
    super();
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading..", "Doing Stuff", true,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        //stuff
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean result){

    pd.dismiss();

    }


}
```

Comment: this just ANR my app. I am executing my asynctask and download notification when the user presses a button.

Comment: I have added the constructor and onPostExecute. This is a rip from my own code which works.

Comment: So you are not using a status bar notification but rather a progress dialog loading bar that displays on the screen...

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

This will work for you until the app is running on foreground. If the app stops the progress bar gets stuck. Its better to download using a service