# Progress bar with Streaming Audio using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-progressbar

Is there a way to show the progress of a song playing with a progress bar and possibly length in terms of minutes and seconds? I would like it in the status bar, but I know  how to do that using a custom notification layout so if someone steers me in the right direction that would be nice. Either with some code or code examples, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to tie in with the NotificationManager classes the progress of the player/mp3.  There was a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865907/android-status-bar-notification-with-progress-bar) that may have what you need...  Also take a look at this for just basic [Progress](http://guides.wikinut.com/Progress-Bar-On-Android/4ws2d1y7/) bar.  And of course read the documentation on [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) and [Status](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) Bar

To get the minutes left to play song, I know VLC player doesn't do that for my SlimDevices server. If you want to do this from via streaming you will have to get the length of the song, then implement your own timer as I am pretty sure that streaming music does not give you the current time left to play song.

Comment: I am using asynctask already with a notification that launches when the user clicks play, but it is just a notification that displays the song title and a play icon. I would like to add to add a progress bar in the notification, which I know how to do. I just don't know how to get the progress of how much has played from a streaming url or get the length in terms of minutes

Comment: You may have to get that info on your own, even VLC player doesn't do that for me.

Comment: oh yikes, i thought i saw a tutorial somewhere from an old android version showing a video or something being buffered from a link